# Correct term in english to call the symbols: "=" / "≥" / "≤"

Tags: terminology

I'm not speak English very well, and I have a question about how I can call the symbols `=` / `≥` / `≤`.

To describe them with a word in Portuguese, we use `sinal` (signal).

Which is the correct term in English? I want a single word to describe all three symbols, not three separate words.

**EDIT**

I want knows the better term to use in my function name `getConstraintSign`.

```
export const getConstraintSign = function(constraint) {
    return constraint.greater ? '≥' : constraint.less ? '≤' : '=';
}
```

Comment: $\,=$ is the equals symbol $\leq$ is the less than or equal to and $\geq$ is the greater than or equal to symbol

Comment: You also say "equal sign" for =.

Comment: I know guys, I need a term to describe them in just one word.

Comment: equivalence relations? but it's a bit more general...

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "sign," though "symbol" is perfectly good.

Comment: I think "sign" will do. But to be sure, show us a complete sentence where you want to use it.

Comment: relation notation?

Comment: "sign" is overloaded, though, so be aware of the context. It also refers to the unary plus or minus sign indicating whether a number is positive or negative.

Comment: @saulspatz so in this case is better use "sign"?

Comment: @TonyS.F. the only equivalence relation pictured above would be $=$.  The other two are orders.  As for the content of the question... I would say it depends on what you want to emphasize about them.  "Character" seems the most general, but characters include `AaBbCc...123...!@#$...` and all other manner of things produced by computers/typewriters/handwriting and the like.  "Symbol" is a bit more specific, but symbols would include many additional things such as $\heartsuit\spadesuit!\&\dots$ as well, things that both are and are not used specifically for mathematics.

Comment: In programming languages, $=$, $\neq$, $>$, $<$, $\leq$, $\geq$ are often called "comparison operators", which seems like a reasonable name. Unfortunately, in mathematics, "operator" also can mean several other things...

Comment: It would be best, as Ethan Bolker commented, if you show us an example of the sentence where you want to use it.

Comment: "Sign" is getting even a bit more specific, but it would also include things like the $-$ in $-5$  (*the "negative sign"*).  Signs in this context are in reference to symbols used in mathematical contexts to my knowledge.  If you were wishing to refer to the specific mathematical concepts of $=,\leq,\geq$, and not referring to simply how they are written, they would be "relations."

Comment: @saulspatz I am go edit my question and show the local where I need use the term.

Comment: @saulspatz I add my problem from the question.

Comment: In this context, I would call it a relational operator, but if you don't like `getRelationalOperator` I would suggest `getOperator.`

Comment: Thanks @saulspatz!

Comment: Comparisons or relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the program context you provide,

```
getConstraintSign
```

is fine.

```
getConstraintSymbol
```

would work too, and is a little more precise, since it's really a glyph (symbol) you're returning.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the @saulspatz suggests use `getConstraintOperator`, my question continues the sames, how is the best term? I believe isn't a better term and all this terms are fine. Am I correct?

Comment: There is no "best term". Any one of the three is clear enough so that someone reading your code will know just what the function does. I would use "symbol" but wouldn't object (wouldn't even comment) on the other choices in a code review.